# Am I using Location.distanceTo() correctly?

Tags: java, android, geolocation

I'm making an app that silences users' ringers when they are in a certain location.  For some reason, though, I don't think the distanceTo() method is working.  When I log the distance, it always says that places are between 9 million and 10 million meters away.  What am I doing wrong?

```
           public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder;
int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST;
ListView placeListView;
ArrayList<String> placeArrayList;
ArrayList<String> latitudeArrayList;
ArrayList<String> longitudeArrayList;
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
ArrayList<Double> latitudeList;
Integer counter;
LocationManager locationManager;
String provider;
double lat;
double lng;
Place place;
static Set<String> set;
static Set<String> set1;
static Set<String> set2;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    placeListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.placeListView);
    latitudeList = new ArrayList<>();
    placeArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    latitudeArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    longitudeArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();


    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);


    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.placeListView);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("bro", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    set = sharedPreferences.getStringSet("names", null);

    set1 = sharedPreferences.getStringSet("lats", null);
    set2 = sharedPreferences.getStringSet("lngs", null);


    placeArrayList.clear();
    latitudeArrayList.clear();
    longitudeArrayList.clear();

    if (set != null) {

        placeArrayList.addAll(set);
        latitudeArrayList.addAll(set1);
        longitudeArrayList.addAll(set2);

    } else {

        placeArrayList.add("Hold to delete");
        set = new HashSet<String>();
        set.addAll(placeArrayList);
        sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("names", set).apply();
        latitudeArrayList.add(String.valueOf("66.56083"));
        set1 = new HashSet<String>();
        set1.addAll(latitudeArrayList);
        sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("lats", set1).apply();
        longitudeArrayList.add(String.valueOf("39.3232"));
        set2 = new HashSet<String>();
        set2.addAll(longitudeArrayList);
        sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("lngs", set2).apply();

    }




    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, placeArrayList);

    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);




    placeListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {


            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .setTitle("Are you sure?")
                    .setMessage("Do you want to delete this place?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                            placeArrayList.remove(position);

                            latitudeArrayList.remove(position);

                            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("bro", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                            if (set == null) {

                                set = new HashSet<String>();
                                set1 = new HashSet<String>();
                                set2 = new HashSet<String>();

                            } else {

                                set.clear();
                                set1.clear();
                                set2.clear();

                            }


                            set.addAll(placeArrayList);
                            set1.addAll(latitudeArrayList);
                            set2.addAll(longitudeArrayList);
                            sharedPreferences.edit().remove("names").apply();
                            sharedPreferences.edit().remove("lats").apply();
                            sharedPreferences.edit().remove("lngs").apply();
                            sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("names", set).apply();
                            sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("lats", set1).apply();
                            sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("lngs", set2).apply();
                            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();


            return false;
        }
    });


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if (location != null) {


        lat = location.getLatitude();

        lng = location.getLongitude();


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(lat) + String.valueOf(lng), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    } else {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to get location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }


    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
            builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
            pickPlace();


        }
    });


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if (location != null) {


        lat = location.getLatitude();

        lng = location.getLongitude();


        if (placeArrayList.size() != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < placeArrayList.size(); i++) {

                Location destination = new Location(provider);
                destination.setLatitude(Float.valueOf(latitudeArrayList.get(i))/1e6);
                destination.setLongitude(Float.valueOf(latitudeArrayList.get(i))/1e6);


                if (location.distanceTo(destination) <= 1000000) {


                    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

                    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);


                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to get location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }


        }
    }
}



public void pickPlace() {

    try {
        startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
            // String toastMsg = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
            //Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            LatLng latLng = place.getLatLng();


            int joe = placeArrayList.size();

            placeArrayList.add(String.valueOf(place.getName()));
            latitudeArrayList.add(String.valueOf(place.getLatLng().latitude));
            longitudeArrayList.add(String.valueOf(place.getLatLng().longitude));
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("bro", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            if (set == null) {

                set = new HashSet<String>();
                set1 = new HashSet<String>();
                set2 = new HashSet<String>();

            } else {

                set.clear();
                set1.clear();
                set2.clear();

            }


            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            set.addAll(placeArrayList);
            set1.addAll(latitudeArrayList);
            set2.addAll(longitudeArrayList);
            sharedPreferences.edit().remove("names").apply();
            sharedPreferences.edit().remove("lats").apply();
            sharedPreferences.edit().remove("lngs").apply();
            sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("names", set).apply();
            sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("lats", set1).apply();
            sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("lngs", set2).apply();





        }

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if (location != null) {


        lat = location.getLatitude();

        lng = location.getLongitude();


        for (int i = placeArrayList.size(); i >= 0; i--) {


            if (lat >= Float.parseFloat(latitudeArrayList.get(i)) - .005 &&
                    lat <= Float.parseFloat(latitudeArrayList.get(i)) + .005 &&
                    lng >= Float.parseFloat(longitudeArrayList.get(i)) - .005 &&
                    lng <= Float.parseFloat(longitudeArrayList.get(i)) + .005) {


                AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);


            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to get location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }


    }
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}


}
```

Comment: What contains `latitudeArrayList` ??

Comment: Also, what is `location`?

Comment: Sorry about that.  I just added the rest of my code.

Answer (score 0):

I think value of Float.valueOf(latitudeArrayList.get(i)) is returned in millions. try `Float.valueOf(latitudeArrayList.get(i))/1e6`

Also Please be specific `placeArrayList` to contents of this array list.

Comment: I just tried dividing it my 1e6 and it still did not work.  Is there anything else I could do?  I just added the rest of my code.

Comment: I think this would solve the problem   `lat = location.getLatitudeE6();

        lng = location.getLongitudeE6(); `